# i have html code with JS in it, i have a problem that the submit button not giving me an alert window, can you correct my code?

Tags: javascript, html, function, if-statement, submit-button

this is part of my code:

Degree:

```
                <script>
                    function F2(){
                        var y = document.getElementById("dd");
                            if (y>=73){
                            window.alert("Your degree is less then required");
                            }
                    }
                </script>
```

it's in a form,
i hope someone help me in my code.

Comment: "y" references the Element, not the value. Try with if (y.value >= 73){...}

Comment: Do you have any specific question about that code?

Comment: An object cannot be compared with a number. You have to have them as the same type before comparing.

Comment: Aside from the JS, you could also wrap those two form controls in a form, then change the button to type submit, then use onsubmit and return false if validation fails. That way, it would submit if it was successful.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to add .value at "y" initialization so you are assigning not value of input field, but the whole field

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <button onclick="F2();">Button</button>
    <input id="dd">
</body>
<script>
    function F2()
    {
        var y = document.getElementById("dd").value;
        if (y >= 73)
        {
            window.alert("Your degree is less then required");
        }
    }
</script>
</html>
```